# Creating directory in bulk using mkdir in shell script

Tags: shell, mkdir

I am trying to create directory in bulk using mkdir through shell script
below is the script

```
#!bin/bash
mkdir /tmp/report*/testfolder*/testdoank
```

when i run it i got an error

```
-bash: ./makefolder.sh: bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

what is wrong?

Comment: You're missing a / in your first line: `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @ajgringo619 that’s the correct answer, please write it up as an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 7):

Apart from the invalid path in the hashbang, which is the cause of the error you get, you also have a problem with the `mkdir` command itself.

Remember that globs only work to list *existing* files, so anything that looks like `mkdir /tmp/foo*` will just pass existing directories as arguments to `mkdir`. If `/tmp/foo1` exists, it will be passed to `mkdir`, which will then complain that it already exists. If `/tmp/foo2` *doesn't* exist, it will *not* be passed to `mkdir`, and will not be created.
You'll have to do something else to create new directories.

It's unclear what directories you want to create, but assuming you want to create a directory `testdoank` under every directory matching `/tmp/report*/testfolder*`, then something like this might do:

```
for dir in /tmp/report*/testfolder*; do
    mkdir "$dir"/testdoank
done
```

Comment: thanks this is what im looking for

Comment: @heff Good! If this solves your issue, please consider ["accepting" the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). This is the best way to show gratitude on this site.  Accepting an answer not only marks the question as resolved, but also signals to _future readers_ that the accepted answer actually solved the issue.  More information about this is available here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

Due to the original formatting of your question, it looked like you were missing the '#' character in your shell declaration. However, the actual error was caused by a missing / in the path of bash.

This is the proper way to determine your shell in a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 1):

The shell script must start with `#!`, not simply `!`.

Comment: That was a formatting problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use

mkdir -p parentdir1/child1 par2/child2/grandchild2

This will create all together, let me know if anything more complex needed